# WPF List View Grouping Scroll Offset with Headers

Tags: wpf, listview, offset

I have an odd issue with a WPF listview:

**Background**

- Using WPF ListView
- Using Grid View to add columns
- Virtualizing
- Using 4 layers of groups to group the data into expanders in a hierarchical structure
- Binding to `CollectionViewSource` defined in window.resources
- Due to indentation of the data (the data is contained in expanders) the headers are offset from the column data so I use `TranslateTransform` to offset the headers by a small amount

**Problem**

Everything displays correctly and in the perfect hierarchical structure, however when I scroll to the right, there comes a point when the data keeps scrolling but the headers stop, which results in an offset between the headers and the data columns.

I am sure this has something to do with the way I am offsetting the headers, and the length of the headers compared to the data but I cant seem to find the reason for this problem.

**List View Scrolled to just before the offset point**

[image: Image Scrolled to just before the offset point]

**List View Scrolled to the end**

[image: Image Scrolled to the end]

**Code**

*nb. I have omitted some style stuff as there is a limit on characters for answers here*

```
<!--  The main grid  -->
                <ListView x:Name="DataGrid"
                          Margin="0"
                          Background="{StaticResource MainBackgroundBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="0"
                          Foreground="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataCollectionView}}"
                          ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="1,2"
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
                    <!--  Some styles and resources exclusive to this list view  -->
                    <ListView.Resources>
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                            <DockPanel>

                                                <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite"
                                                              Width="600"
                                                              MinWidth="0"
                                                              MinHeight="0"
                                                              Margin="1"
                                                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                              ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                                                              DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                                              FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                                              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                                              FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                                                              FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                                                              FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                              IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                              Template="{StaticResource AnimatedExpanderButton}" />
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite"
                                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                                  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                                                  Focusable="false"
                                                                  Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                                                <Setter TargetName="HeaderSite" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite" Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Title">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                        <!--  Styles the column headers  -->
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <!--  Add the event handler for a right click on the header  -->
                            <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonUp" Handler="GridViewColumnHeader_MouseRightButtonUp" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GradientBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="20" />
                            <!--  Offset the column headers to match the column data as the expanders will have offset the data  -->
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="13" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1">
                                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <!--  The two column re sizers  -->
                                                <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper"
                                                       Width="18"
                                                       Margin="0,0,-10,0"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                       Background="Black"
                                                       Cursor="SizeWE">
                                                    <Thumb.Template>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent">
                                                                <Rectangle Width="1"
                                                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Thumb.Template>
                                                </Thumb>
                                                <!--  The main content of the header  -->
                                                <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderContent"
                                                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                                                  Margin="5"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <!--  Templates each level  -->
                    <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <!--  Style for groups at the top level. this level is equivalent to a single database  -->
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                <Border Margin="1"
                                                        Background="{StaticResource FandFBrush}"
                                                        BorderBrush="Black"
                                                        BorderThickness="2"
                                                        CornerRadius="3">
                                                    <Expander Margin="0"
                                                              FontSize="12"
                                                              FontWeight="Bold"
                                                              Foreground="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}"
                                                              Header="{Binding Name}"
                                                              IsExpanded="True">
                                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="IP"
                                                                        Margin="0"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                                                    </Expander>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                        <!--  Style for groups at the second level. this level is equivalent to a single case  -->
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                <Border Margin="0"
                                                        Background="{StaticResource MainBackgroundBrush}"
                                                        BorderBrush="Black"
                                                        BorderThickness="2"
                                                        CornerRadius="3">
                                                    <Expander Margin="0"
                                                              FontSize="12"
                                                              FontWeight="Bold"
                                                              Foreground="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}"
                                                              Header="{Binding Name}"
                                                              IsExpanded="True">
                                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="IP"
                                                                        Margin="0"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
                                                                        VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                                                    </Expander>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                        <!--  Style for groups at the third level. this level is equivalent to a single sample type  -->
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                <Border Margin="1"
                                                        BorderBrush="Black"
                                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                                        CornerRadius="3">
                                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="IP"
                                                                    Margin="0"
                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                        <!--  Style for groups at the fourth level. this level is equivalent to a single sample  -->
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                <Border Margin="0,0,0,1"
                                                        Background="Transparent"
                                                        BorderBrush="Black"
                                                        BorderThickness="2,2,2,2"
                                                        CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"
                                                        Visibility="{Binding Items[0].Fragment.Sample.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                                    <Expander Margin="0"
                                                              FontSize="12"
                                                              FontWeight="Bold"
                                                              Foreground="Black"
                                                              IsExpanded="True">
                                                        <Border Grid.Row="0"
                                                                Margin="1,0,1,1"
                                                                Background="{StaticResource MainBackgroundBrush}"
                                                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                BorderThickness="2,1,2,2"
                                                                CornerRadius="2">
                                                            <Grid>
                                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <!--  The measurements themselves  -->
                                                                <Border Grid.Row="0"
                                                                        Margin="0"
                                                                        Background="{StaticResource MainBackgroundBrush}"
                                                                        BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                        BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                                                                        CornerRadius="0">
                                                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="IP"
                                                                                    Margin="0"
                                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
                                                                                    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                                                                </Border>   </Grid>
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </Expander>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you post minimal, complete, verifiable source producing the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: it looks like two extra columns are in the gridview which have no headers associated with them. but you need to post a minimal and complete source if you want us to help further.